# Detailed multitasking monitoring

Tags: monitoring, multitasking, preemption

I'm trying to put together a model of a computer and run some simulations on it (part of a school assignment). It's a very simple model - a CPU, a disk and a process generator that generates user processes that take turns in using the CPU and accessing the disk (I've decided to omit the various system processes, because according to Process Explorer they use next to no CPU time - I'm basing this on the Microsoft Process Explorer tool, running on Windows 7). And this is where I've stopped at.

I have no idea how to get relevant data on how often do various processes read/write to disk and how much data at once, and how much time they spend using the CPU. Let's say I want to get some statistics for some typical operations on a PC - playing music/movies, browsing the internet, playing games, working with Office, video editing and so on...is there even a way to gather such data?

I'm simulating preemptive multitasking using RR with a time quantum of 15ms for switching processes, and this is how it looks:
->Process gets to CPU
->Process does its work in 0-15ms, gives up the CPU or is cut off
And now, two options arise:
a)process just sits and waits before it gets the CPU again or before it gets some user input if there is nothing to do
b)process requested data from disk, and does not rejoin the queue until said data is available

And i would like the decision between a) and b) in the model be done based on a probability, for example 90% for a) and 10% for b). But I do not know how to get those percentages to be at least a bit realistic for a certain type of process. Also, how much data can and does a process typically access at once?

Any hints, sources, utilities available for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found an answer myself, albeit an unreliable one.

The Process Explorer utility for Windows measures disk I/O - by volume and by occurences. So there's a rough way to get the answer:
say a process performs 3 000 reads in 30 minutes, whilst using 2% of CPU during that time (assuming a single core CPU). So the process has used 36000ms of CPU time, divided into ~5200 blocks (this is the unreliable part - the process in all proabbility does not use the whole of the time slot, so I'll just divide by half the time slot). 3000/5200 gives a 57% chance of reading data after using the CPU.

I hope I did not misunderstand the "reads" statistic in Process Explorer.